# PHP: Not changing the value of a variable

Tags: javascript, php

I have a problem in confirmation message when the USER click CANCEL the value of `$IsCanceled = "yes"`
then when I click OK the value of `$IsCanceled = "no"..

The problem is, when I click the OK the value of $IsCanceled is still yes...

```
<?php
 else { ?>
        <script>
        var myVar = "<?php echo $bldg[$i]; ?> station is already full. Do you want to save the other networks?";
        if (confirm(myVar)) {
        <?php $IsCanceled = "no";?>
    } else {
        <?php
        $IsCanceled = "yes";
        ?>          
    }
        </script>
        <?php
    }
//and so on...
```

I already traced everthing but its still "yes" the value..

Thanks

Comment: You can't mix apples and oranges, or client and server side scripting. Javascript is client side while PHP is server side.

Comment: You cannot mix php and js that way. PHP is the server side language and JS is the cliend side language.

Comment: what is confirm method?

Comment: If you want to echo something that's possible,but you can't do anything better with php inside javascript.

Comment: @SJnawali...its a confirmation message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP and Javascript.
Two completely different languages used in various different tasks.

What you have written above tries to mix two languages, which if you were writing in any other environment you wouldn't even consider doing. The above script you have written, **will run its PHP when on the server**, and produce an **output** that is sent to the browser.

In your case, that will look something like:

```
<script>
var myVar = "i station is already full. Do you want to save the other networks?";
if (confirm(myVar)) {
} else {
}
</script>
```

That is the exact output of your code at the moment. If you want to navigate the user to "save to other networks", you would have to create a hidden HTML `form`, with an `<input type="hidden" ..` that can hold the answer you need. Then, with Javascript, you can show your confirmation dialog and populate the HTML form, submit it, and handle it again with PHP.

Think of it like Tennis. You cannot change the way you hit the ball, after already sending it to the opponent. In this case, you can program both sides and make them handle the tennis ball accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

php is server side scripting it can not assigned without page refresh.

Use javascript(client side scripting) variable to assign yes or no

```
else
{ 
?>
<script>
var myVar = "<?php echo $bldg[$i]; ?> station is already full. Do you want to save the other networks?";
if (confirm(myVar)) {
    IsCanceled = "no";
} else {
    IsCanceled = "yes";        
}
alert(IsCanceled);
</script>
<?php
}
```

Comment: @Salim....its already working...but how can I pass the value of varibale in javascript to php? because i need to create an if else in php side... thanks for reply

Comment: It is posible using ajax

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do some logic at client side you need to use JS without PHP in it.
And if you need to do logic server side so you need to POST or GET to the server.

Just open your page as source right after it loaded and you will see, that in place where you put PHP condition will be nothing.

It's because PHP already done all it's work. Check $IsCanceled and show page to you.

ALSO note, that if you need to check instead of assign you need to use double equals sign instead one e.g. `if($IsCanceled == 'no')` will check if variable `IsCanceled` equals string `'no'`. BUT `if($IsCanceled = 'no')` tells php to assign string `'no'` to variable `IsCanceled` it will be TRUE always because it's assignment and result of assignment is TRUE